# qt3d library Cross compilation linking error

Tags: qt3d

I want to crosscompile qt3d library example hardware AM3355 starter kit but I get following error

> [linux-devkit]:~/Documents/qt3d/examples/quick3d/monkeygod> qmake-qt4
>
> [linux-devkit]:~/Documents/qt3d/examples/quick3d/monkeygod> make
>   arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ 
>   --sysroot=/home/deep/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-06.00.00.00/linux-devkit/sysroots/armv7ahf-vfp-neon-3.2-oe-linux-gnueabi
>   -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/deep/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-06.00.00.00/linux-devkit/sysroots/armv7ahf-vfp-neon-3.2-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib
>   -o ../../../bin/monkeygod main.o    -L/home/deep/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-06.00.00.00/linux-devkit/sysroots/armv7ahf-vfp-neon-3.2-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib
>   -lQt3DE -lQt3DQuickE -lQtDeclarativeE -lQtScriptE -lQtSvgE -lQtSqlE -lQtXmlPatternsE -lQtOpenGLE -lQtGuiE -lQtNetworkE -lQtCoreE -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lGLES_CM -lIMGegl -lsrv_um -lpthread  /home/deep/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-06.00.00.00/linux-devkit/sysroots/i686-arago-linux/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lQt3DE
>   /home/deep/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-06.00.00.00/linux-devkit/sysroots/i686-arago-linux/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lQt3DQuickE collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [../../../bin/monkeygod] Error 1

can any one please help me out of this?